# Databricks Delta tables vs SQL Server Delta table

Tags: sql-server, databricks, delta-lake

Is there is a difference between Sql Delta table and Databricks Delta table? It looks like for SQL we use the name on a conceptual basis. The table that stores the difference of Base table is Delta. Is it the same for databricks?

Comment: They are completely different. Can you provide a reference to your "SQL Delta Table" because that's a conceptual thing vs databricks delta which is an actual product

Comment: https://www.wapshere.com/missmiis/how-to-make-a-sql-delta-table

Comment: Same concept except that databricks delta does this automatically, but I don't think it has a insert/update/delete flag, just a "point in time" view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Databricks Delta is storage layer that provides ACID transactions & other improvements to store big amounts of data for use with Apache Spark.  It used to store *complete datasets*, that could be updated if necessary.  [Delta is open source project](https://delta.io/), with some enhancements available at Databricks platform.